# Is the 'Nikon pronunciation' question relevant?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, migration

I'm surprised more people haven't queried the relevance of the [How should Nikon be pronounced](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13505/how-should-nikon-be-pronounced) question - surely this is way off topic? Rowland Shaw has posted a link to the Japanese Language site in the comments - should this perhaps be migrated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that Nikon is a Japanese company, that does not necessarily mean this is a question about the Japanese Language. Pronunciation is of a word is generally dependent upon the language it is spoken in, and therefor it will be spoken differently in different locales. There is no single site that this question really belongs at, as it could fit on our site, the Japanese Language site, or even the English Language site. It could be migrated...but to which one? At least here on PhotoSE, it does fit regardless of language...it is a question about a camera manufacturer, and while pronunciation is not specifically on topic, the community doesn't seem to think it is particularly off-topic in this case either. If a new SEN language site pops up in the future where it would actually fit (i.e. General Languages and Usage), I could see it being migrated where there, as it would be a better fit.

Comment: "the community doesn't seem to think it is particularly off-topic" - that's what puzzles me! I don't think it relates to the art or science of photography at all, if you apply the rules strictly pedantically. It may be that there isn't a specific site for this sort of question, but that doesn't mean it belongs here. Given the speed with which other OT questions are closed, I'm just perplexed.

Comment: Well, I try not to just go around closing questions until the community has had a chance to respond on their own, or I get a bunch of flags or comments about topics in chat. I'd prefer to let the community voice speak first. Even though it isn't an art or science question, it is still directly related to photography, since gear (and the names of gear) are the third leg of the tripod of photography. ;) The question has five upvotes, and the first answer has 13 upvotes. I would prefer not to take contrary action on my own, and I think there are different views on the "on/off topicness" here.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts - I'll file under 'nowt so queer as folk'!

Comment: You say Tomato, I say...

Answer (score 5):

I think how to pronounce a common brand of camera is quite relevant to a photography site.